# WebView videos not playing on samsung devices

Tags: android, webview

I have a simple webview ,nothing complex

```
    URL = getIntent().getExtras().getString(FinalVariables.LOAD_URL);
    mWebView =(WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(URL))
    mWebView.loadUrl(URL);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    });
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

But for some reason if the opened page has a video in it, it won't get played

[image]

this is what I am seeing now.But when I run this same code on sony device,no problems there.I tried enabling the `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` but didn't work.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this and was quite simple.Adding a single line on  `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` fixed the problem ie,

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Hope this will help someone.